# Running Junit test parallely with csv test data

Tags: automated-testing, java, test-automation-framework, junit

I have a csv test data file with 50+ test data in it. I want my JUnit test to process these 50+ test data in parallel than serially. How can we do that? Is there a framework that can do that?

**Junit test:**

```
@Test
@FileParameters(value = "classpath:csvFileName.csv", mapper = CsvWithHeaderMapper.class)
public void testData(parameters)
{
  //code to test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old but for the people who faces similar problems there are some good news. **JUnit5** supports parallel test run out of the box. Such execution works with data providers so parallel threads would use their own particular pieces of data.

Here are some refs:

- [How to configure parallel execution in JUnit5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution)
- [How to configure test parameterization in JUnit5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions that add parallelization to JUnit:

- [JUnit toolbox](https://github.com/MichaelTamm/junit-toolbox)
- [EasyTest](http://www.kumaranuj.com/2013/07/run-your-unit-tests-in-parallel.html?view=classic)
- [customized Parameterized runner](http://hwellmann.blogspot.pt/2009/12/running-parameterized-junit-tests-in.html)

However, I'm not sure how they work with .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

By default I believe it runs tests sequentially.

JUnit 4.6 introduced an experimental ParallelRunner to run tests in parallel - I don't know of its current status. I would expect parallelism to remain an "opt-in" feature by default though. (Judging by other answers, it looks like this is now here to stay but in a slightly different form - and still opt-in.)

Good Luck